# Can Fubuki use her powers to power up somebody else?

Tags: one-punch-man

Recently in the manga,

> Fubuki used Bomb's energy to heal TankTop Master.

Now, if she can transfer someone's energy or vitality, or whatever, to another person to heal him (which, among other things, presumably would not involve restoring tissues, but returning stamina, also after healing someone else, this person could fight again), does this mean she can use the same technique to power another healthy person up? If I recall correctly, in other of One's mangas (Mob's Psycho) , psychics could use his powers to unlock other person's psychic powers, or to enhance their own strength.

What about Fubuki here? Can Fubuki use her powers to power up somebody else?

Comment: I think until now there is no evidence for it. However, it looks like she didn't move Bomb's energy to TankTop, she used that power for herself to have enough mana to heal TankTop (personally, I think the author just add it randomly). If Fubuki has the power as you said, all she needs to do is transfer energy from monster to hero, then ez win.